# How to access the object state from interface reference in JAVA

Tags: java, guava

I want t know is there any flexibility provided in JAVA to access the state of the object wrapped with interface reference. I am designing a cache library using guava cache. Guava cache is a generic. In my library I want to instantiate this Generic library with some generic type using the interfaces. as below.

```
LoadingCache<CacheKey, CacheValue> cache;
```

where CacheKey and CacheValue are interfaces.

```
public interface CacheKey {
    CacheValue calculateValue();
}

public interface CacheValue {

}
```

I am successfully able to use this cache for storing the type pairs that implement these interfaces.
But the problem I am facing is When I retrieve the values from the cache using

```
cache.get(key);
```

It returns me CacheValue reference with actual object wrapped inside it. I need to do static cast to the actual object type to access the underlying object's state like below.

```
AccountID aid = (AccountID)cache.get(key);
```

Is there any way I can avoid this static casting and access the underlying object's state without typecasting?

**UPDATE**

I am instantiating the guava cache in my library to support any key type and value type not only AccountID. As I am instantiating the cache it should have the concrete types. not generic like CacheKey

Comment: What purpose does the empty `CacheValue` interface have? Why aren't you using generics? Should you be creating a library when you don't have the experience for it?

Comment: You can make your `CacheKey` generic as well, as in `CacheKey<AccountID>`, with `get()` returning `AccountID` without the need for a cast.

Comment: I have updated the question. @Kayaman . Purpose of empty value is to just act as wrapper

Comment: An empty interface is a marker interface, a wrapper is a different thing. Marker interfaces are pretty obsolete these days too, as annotations tend to be more flexible. I still don't see a purpose for `CacheValue`. Your design also seems to indicate that a cache value can be calculated by the key alone, which suggests [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) more than caching in the way you're trying to design it.

Comment: @Kayaman my backend cache is Guava. I want to store any type of key and value pair in it. Guava is a generic cache. I need to instantiate it and provide the interfaces for interacting with it. Guava provides multiple ways for entering values to it either by using cache.put or using cache.get(key) if the value is not present for the key in the cache it tries to calculate it using the calculateValue method of the CacheKey.

Comment: You can _either_ define the cache as a  `LoadingCache<WhateverKey, AccountId>`, or explicitly cast.  There are no real alternatives other than these two choices.  Otherwise, what would the cache do if the value in the cache _wasn't_ an `AccountId` but was some other kind of `CacheValue`?